# MongoDB case insensitive key search

Tags: mongodb, key, case-insensitive

I am able to query values without regard to case, but I would like to to query keys insensitively, so users can type them in all lower case.

This doesn't work, because it is not valid JSON:

```
{
   /^lastName$/i: "Jones"
}
```

Is there a strategy I could use for this, besides just making a new collection of keys as values?

Comment: Who -1'd this? It's a reasonably valid question. Resetting to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this.

MongoDB is *"schema-free"* but that should not be confused with *"doesn't have a schema"*. There's an implicit assumption that your code has some control over the names of the keys that actually appear in the system.

Let's flip the question around.

- *Is there a good reason that users are inserting case-sensitive keys?*
- *Can you just cast all keys to lower-case when they're inserted?*

Again, MongoDB assumes that you have some knowledge of the available keys. Your question implies that you have no knowledge of the available keys. You'll need to close this gap.

Comment: "There is currently no way to do this."

Is this answer still valid today?

Comment: This will likely always be the case. Change queries to support ranges on the key is a ton of work. Also, it cannot be indexed which is a big deal.

Comment: Rather than use terms like "no schema" or "schemaless" when explaining mongodb and similar db systems, I find it creates less confusion to say they have a variable or unrestricted schema by default.

Comment: Mongodb supports case insensitive indexing now.