# Is it ok to use MongoDB when we have no idea about the availabe keys?

Tags: mongodb, screen-scraping, nosql

We are scraping a huge products website.

So, we will get and persist so many products, and almost each product has a different set of features/details.

Naturally, we consider using a NoSQL database (MongoDB) for this job. We will make a collection "products", and a document for each product where each key/value pair map to detail_name/detail_description of the product.

Since products are quite different, we have almost no idea what are the product details/features. In other words, we have no knowledge of the available keys.

According to this link [MongoDB case insensitive key search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780087/mongodb-case-insensitive-key-search/6780192#comment15780231_6780192), It is a "gap" for MongoDB (that we do not have some idea of the available keys).

Is this true? If yes, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key problem isn't that much of an issue for MongoDB provided you can live with a slightly different schema and big indexes :

Normally you would do something like :

```
{
    productId :..
    details : {
        detailName1 : detailValue1,
        detailName2 : detailValue2;
    }
}
```

But if you do this you can index the details field :

```
{
    productId :..
    details : [
        {field : detailName1, value : detailValue1},
        {field : detailName2, value : detailValue2}
    ]
}
```

Do note that this will result in a very big index. Not necessarily a problem but something to be aware of. The index will then be `{details.field:1, details.value:1}` (or just `{details:1}` if you're not adding additional fields per detail).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is an innovative answer.

Anyway, I am choosing MongoDB instead of RDBMS(MySQL) to avoid the EAV (entity-attribute-value) database design pattern.

If we follow your approach, then our schema design will be somehow similar (at least conceptually) to EAV. So, does this approach have any of the EAV drawbacks (i.e. more complex queries, bad readability)?

Comment: It has roughly the same drawbacks. EAV is almost impossible to avoid if performance is a big consideration. MongoDB supports your original plan but query performance will not scale linearly. If your key set is large but bounded to, say, 100 different values you can consider creating an index for each key you find. The combined index size will be quite a bit higher than one "key" index. I think there is an upper bound to the amount of indexes you can have per collection though so again you need an upper bound.

Comment: You are right, It seems MongoDB limits the number of indices per collection to 40. Anyway, we expect to have thousands of different keys in the key set. 

In fact, we are using EAV to be able to make queries on the key name itself.
for example (excuse my SQL-like syntax):
Fetch all products with name="computer" and detail_name='%RAM%' and detail_value='%2%GB%'.

Unfortuately, in MongoDB, this query seems to be impossible without using EAV. Am I right?

Comment: No the query is possible it just wont be using indexes. You could query that directly using {name:"computer", details.ram : "2Gb"}. This will only return document that have a "ram" field in the details embedded document witht he value "2Gb". It will ignore document that do not have the field at all.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've scraped all of the data you could examine it to determine if there is a field/set of fields in the documents that you could add an index to in order to improve performance.